# Synchronize Windows feature in ImageJ

Tags: imagej

I'm using the Synchronize Windows feature in ImageJ 1.47.  To support some debugging, I want to be able to see the pixel values at the cursor location in all my windows simultaneously.

By default the "master" ImageJ window displays the RGB values of the pixel at my cursor location in the "current" window.  This is nice, but what I really want is to simultaneously see the RGB values at my cursor location in ALL of the synchronized windows.

Any suggestions for doing this?  It seems like the easiest way would be if there were some setting that would cause the RGB value to be displayed in each image window instead of only in the master window.  But I can't find such a setting.  Perhaps there's some other plugin for this?

Alternatively, does anybody know of other viewing software besides ImageJ that supports a feature like Synchronize Windows?